# How can I handleEvent two events with the same event type?

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how can I handle two events with the same event type. I would like to differentiate both buttons. When I click btn1 I would like to handleEvent and call doSomething1 and when I click btn2 doSomething2.

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {
        const btn1 = document.querySelector('#button1');
        const btn2 = document.querySelector('#button2');

        btn1.addEventListener('click', this);
        btn2.addEventListener('click', this);
    }

    handleEvent(e) {
        if (e.type === 'click') {
            this.doSomething1();
            this.doSomething2();
        }
    }

    doSomething1() {
        console.log('something1');
    }

    doSomething2() {
        console.log('something2');
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work with what you have?

Comment: @siride I edited my question. I think now is more clear. I know how to do that by doing this: btn2.addEventListener('click', () =>this.doSomething1()) But I would like to know how to do that by using handleEvent. When I have different events (click, input etc.) I don't have any problem, but when event is repeated I don't know how to differentiate.

Comment: You mean how to find out which button the event came from? You can look at e.target and compare it to your button objects, or check its id property.

Comment: @siride Yes, I mean that. I thought there might be another way to do it besides the one you mention. So if I would like to do my handleEvent more dynamic I would have to do this: return this[`${e.target.id}Event`](e); and name my function like the id of the button follow by "Event" e.g.: idnameEvent()

Comment: You could make it that complicated. I would never do it this way. I would just bind the event handlers directly to handler functions. That is btn1.addEventListener('click', this.handleBtn1Click.bind(this));. No matter what you do, you are somewhere going to have to have a look up table or complicated logic. I dont see a need.

Comment: @siride Ok thanks. I'll do it that way